# Apache Camel error starting bundle

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Learning Apache Camel-
Trying to deploy an application on jboss-fuse-6.1.0.redhat-379.

The POM is as follows

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.dao</groupId>
        <artifactId>camelDAO</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>bundle</packaging>
        <properties>
        <camel-version>2.13.0</camel-version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                <version>${camel-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
                <version>${camel-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${camel-version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

In database config file have configured the following

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/univ" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>


<bean id="sqlComponent"                                       
      class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

and in route have made call to sql component

```
<to uri="sqlComponent:{{sql.insertData}}" />
```

while deploying on fuse getting-

```
Error executing command: Error starting bundles:
    Unable to start bundle 255: Unresolved constraint in bundle  
com.dao.came
lDAO [255]: Unable to resolve 255.0: missing requirement [255.0]   
osgi.wiring.pac
kage; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.component.sql)  
(version>=2.13.0)(!(
version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 253.0: missing   
requirement [253.
0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel) 
(version>=2.13.0
)(!(version>=3.0.0)))]
```

Have installed the jars using wrap:install, still getting the above error

Kindly help me figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import missing packages:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Description>${project.description}</Bundle-Description>
                <Import-Package>
                    *,
                    org.apache.camel.osgi,
                    org.apache.camel.component.sql,
                    org.apache.camel
                </Import-Package>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And camel-sql feature must be installed.

UPDATED:

> Have installed the jars using wrap:install

You need to do that only for database drivers, all other must be installed by features.

```
>    <bean id="sqlComponent"                                       
>          class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
>          <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    
>    </bean>
```

That can be implemented simpler:

```
<to uri="sql:{{sql.insertData}}?dataSource=dataSource" />
```

And please, check your Camel version, installed on jboss fuse server, it must match the one specified in your project.

Comment: Alexey- Thanks for the reply. After using  features:install camel-sql, still getting the same exception. Also on using the imports you mentioned get                                                                                                                 Error executing command: Duplicate import: org.apache.camel.component.sql                                                                                                                                                                               Similarly duplicate error for camel and osgi.

Comment: Did you add using features:install camel-jdbc and everything else in your POM which is not part of camel-core? Your error indicates that karaf requires a jar which it cannot find.

Comment: Thanks a lot alexey it worked.actually the jboss fuse camel version was 2.12.0. Saw this using features:list. So had to change the dependency version in POM to 2.12.0. Also Can i change the camel version on jboss fuse server so that I can use the latest jar files? –

Comment: Theoretically, you can try to change Camel version manually, but it is not so easy (uninstall all old features, add new feature repository, install new features). I use Apache Servicemix, and when i need to upgrade Camel version, i upgrade whole Servicemix server, that not so long.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Mysql Connector in Jboss Fuse.
For install we need to run the following statement in the Fuse terminal.

***osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39***

Version can be changed based on your mysql connector used.

Once after install. try to run your project.